# How do I control a brushless DC motor without an ESC with Arduino

Tags: arduino, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

Is there a way to control brushless DC motor removed from a CD-ROM drive without using an ESC by using an Arduino.

Comment: I'm sure there's a way, although you may need a separate power supply for the motor. What's an ESC?

Comment: It amounts to building your own ESC (Electronic Speed Controller).

Comment: Do you have more characteristic data about the motor?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot control a brushless motor by just plugging it in an Arduino. You might have enough parts in your junk drawer to implement a simple brushless controller, but it's not as simple as an H bridge. You need to be able to read in the Hall effect sensor inputs and switch the FETs correctly. You can google for brushless ESC schematics, but [here's an example](http://www.masinaelectrica.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/12.png). If I were you, I'd just buy a pre-made one from HobbyKing or something.

Comment: Note that many ESC's have the same ATMega chip as an Arduino at their core to drive their bridges.  Hall effect sensors or typically not used in these hobby market designs, but rather sensing winding back EMF.  And that works even on motors which do have sensors.